# What does the parable of the Fig Tree mean?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-luke, parables

> **[Luke 13:6-9 (NIV)](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+13&version=NIV#en-NIV-25525)**
>
> **6** Then he told this parable: “A man had a fig tree growing in
> his vineyard, and he went to look for fruit on it but did not find
> any. **7** So he said to the man who took care of the vineyard, ‘For three
> years now I’ve been coming to look for fruit on this fig tree and
> haven’t found any. Cut it down! Why should it use up the soil?’
>
> **8** “‘Sir,’ the man replied, ‘leave it alone for one more year, and
> I’ll dig around it and fertilize it. **9** If it bears fruit next year,
> fine! If not, then cut it down.’”

Could someone explain what the parable means?

Comment: Some help from the [intratext](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0839/1/NM.HTM)

Comment: I can give you no help on what lesson to draw from this tale, but I've heard that the tale itself is reasonable, as there was a tax on fruit trees. Incidentally, fresh ripe figs are delicious. My mother has a fig tree in her greenhouse. Mmmm ....